# Meaning of "called into the opening from the Goshen, NY jail"

Tags: meaning

The sentence is:

> Sorokin called into the opening from the Goshen, NY jail where she is being held to thank everyone there for supporting her.
>
> The crowd broke into a "Free Anna Delvey" chant.

What baffles me is: "called into the opening from the Goshen". I'm not sure how to interpret this.

Is it like:

1. the Sorokin girl was called to be in the Goshen jail entrance?

OR is it like:

2. someone called the Sorokin girl from a callphone and the caller was in  Goshen jail entrance?

OR neither?

Comment: More context is needed to be sure, but I'm parsing "opening" as an event she's "calling into" (appearing virtually at) while physically in the Goshen jail. Took me a minute though.

Comment: One detail that might be confusing: the comma after "Goshen" doesn't mean the end of the phrase; it's a customary usage when naming a city within a state ("Goshen, New York").

Answer (score 2):

I found it [here](https://www.fox5ny.com/news/free-anna-delvey-art-show-in-nyc). It's a Fox site. Without context your extract is pretty meaningless.

The **opening** is the first day of the exhibition at the Delancey Street art gallery. She used her phone to call the gallery (from the jail) to thank her supporters.

["*from the ... jail where she is being held to thank everyone*" is faithful to the original. It's an amusing way to thank everyone.]